# MySql trigger to replace text

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

everybody!

I have a trigger to replace text BEFORE INSERT to table, i have a text in which need change one word

```
SET NEW.shipping_method = CASE WHEN NEW.shipping_method LIKE 'weight' THEN 'Svars' ELSE 
NEW.shipping_method END
```

But this command change all text who contain word weight to svars.

Thanks

P.S. I read a documentation on sql but can't  find the correct definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to *replace* a word in text, then use `replace()`:

```
SET NEW.shipping_method = REPLACE(NEW.shipping_method, 'weight', 'Svars')
```